# 389 ldap server admin account disable

Tags: ldap, centos7

I have done 389 server setup on Centos 7 also authenticate the client using sssd but I need to disable admin account on the server and create another account with the same privileges.could you please help me for same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are talking about LDAP admin account (olcRootDN) or a ssh user.

If you are talking about LDAP admin account, you can rename it this way:

1. stop slapd
2. dump the whole ldif with "slapcat > ldif.txt"
3. modify every appearance of cn=oldadmin,dc=your,dc=domain with
   cn=newadmin,dc=your,dc=domain (you can't modify the domain, just the
   "cn=xxxx")
4. modify olcRootDN entry in database config to point to your new user
5. delete your ldap data and "slapadd < ldif.txt"
6. start slapd

If you are talking about renaming a SSH account, you can run:

```
usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>
```

probably you'll want to rename the group as well:

```
groupmod -n <newgroup> <oldgroup>
```

Comment: and From 389 ldap directory server console?